# Achieving an SFINAE-like effect in an if-else block

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, conditional-compilation

I would like to be able to write something like

```
template <typename T> void foo() {
    // ...
    if (is_nice<T>::value) {
        bar_which_is_defined_only_for_nice_types<T>();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile this (g++ 4.9.3, no optimization) I get a complaint about `bar_which_is_defined_only_for_nice_types`. How can I achieve the desired effect without resorting to 2 definitions of `foo()`?

Comment: It is not possible in that way. It was proposal to [open std](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3613.pdf). Use function overloading in the asnwer of @Praetorian below.

Answer (score 8):

You can tag dispatch based on `is_nice<T>`

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_nice : std::false_type {};
template<>
struct is_nice<int> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
void do_nice_things(std::true_type)
{
    bar_which_is_defined_only_for_nice_types<T>();
}

template<typename T>
void do_nice_things(std::false_type)
{
}

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    do_nice_things<T>(is_nice<T>{});
}
```